# How can I hand over row object from datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces DataTable with a lot of entries. When I click a row I do this here:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{detailsBean.showData(data)}">
```

So what I want to do is to call a method in my bean and hand over the data from the  clicked table row but when I debug it the object is always null. I'm not sure how to deal with this. Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you tried enabling `selection` on the data table, such as `selection="#{detailsBean.selectedRecord}"` and then changing your `detailsBean.showData` to use `this.selectedRecord` instead of taking a parameter? (your `p:ajax` should have `process="@this"` at least...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I get the selected item from datatable

xhtml:

```
<p:datatable value="#{yourBean.listObject}" selection="single" ---- and other suff---->

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener=#"{yourBean.aMethodInBean}"/>

</p:datatable>
```

bean:

```
YourObject yourObject;
List<YourObject> listObject;
-----
public void aMethodInBean(SelectEvent event) {
    yourObject = (YourObject) event.getObject();
}
```

Comment: And what parameter should I pass from the frontend to the backend? So which parameter should be SelectEvent?

Comment: no, just use the listener like that without parameter. look at select events example here https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Xhtml :

```
<p:dataTable    value="#{bean.list}" selectionMode="single" selection="{bean.selectedEmployee}">

      <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  listener="#{bean.anyMethod()}"/>

</p:dataTable>
```

Here ajax is not mandatory

Bean :

```
 List<Employee> list ;
 Employee selectedEmployee;


 public void anyMethod(){

 }
```